# Magento Setting Up Cron "cron.sh: line 26: $'\r': command not found"

Tags: magento-1.9, cron, crontab

Recently i setup a fresh install of Magento 1.9.2 upon configuring cron i get the following error when i try to execute

```
bash /path/to/my/magento/root/cron.sh

ERROR :cron.sh: line 26: $'\r': command not found
```

I also get the same result with:

```
php cron.php
```

I can't change the cron.sh to :

```
chmod -x cron.sh
```

because i am not part of sudo. My option is limited with cron.sh. I am using Webfaction hosting if this can be of any help.

Can anyone help me with this ? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [your stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38841316/magento-configuring-cronjob-cron-sh-line-26-r-command-not-found):

This is an encoding problem in the file's line endings, probably a result of the way you've deployed/installed the code.

Don't copy and paste file contents - upload the file as it ships with the fresh Magento installation using FTP or a git repository to deploy it.

See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11616835/r-command-not-found-bashrc-bash-profile) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18608380/r-command-not-found) (for example).